# Routing variable in Angular2

Tags: angular, routes

I've read over the documentation for the new Angular router. The example they have for routing to a variable is this:

Component/Module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngFuturisticRouter'])
.controller('AppController', ['$router', function($router) {
  $router.config({ path: '/user/:id' component: 'user' });
  this.user = { name: 'Brian', id: 123 };
});
```

HTML/Template:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController as app">
  <a router-link="user({id: app.user.id})">{{app.user.name}}</a>
</div>
```

Here is my component:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', component: Home, as: 'home' },
  { path: '/displays/:id', component: DisplayDetails, as: 'display-details' }
])
```

And my HTML/Template:

```
<div class="col-md-3" *ng-for="#display of displays">
    <a [router-link]="['/display-details({id: display.id})']"><display-card ></display-card></a>
</div>
```

I've also tried instead of putting the component alias `(display-details)` I've tried putting the actual path and the component it self but they all give me the same error:

```
EXCEPTION: Component "App" has no route named "display-details({id: display.id})". in [null]
```

Comment: Try with `[router-link]="['/display-details', {id: display.id}]"`, btw, what version are you using?

Comment: @EricMartinez Thank you man! I'm using alpha.37. BTW you've really helped me out with Angular2 I think you've answered all the questions I've had

Comment: @EricMartinez You wanna make it an answer so I can give a check mark

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As suggested by @ThreeAccents

Quoting from the documentation [RouterLink](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html).

> RouterLink expects the value to be an array of route names, followed by the params for that level of routing. For instance `['/Team', {teamId: 1}, 'User', {userId: 2}]` means that we want to generate a link for the `Team` route with params `{teamId: 1}`, and with a child route User with params `{userId: 2}`.

So the solution is to change your `routerLink` to as follows :

```
<div class="col-md-3" *ng-for="#display of displays">
    <a [routerLink]="['/display-details', {id: display.id}]">
       <display-card ></display-card>
    </a>
</div>
```

Glad it worked for you :)

Comment: I updated your answer to reflect the API as of 2.0-beta. I think it's still missing 2 things. The link `/display-details` should be `/DisplayDetails` and the route 'as' parameter has been changed to 'name'.

Comment: I had to use string concatenation like `<a [routerLink]="['/display-details'+display.id]">` , but this helped me get most of the way there

Answer (score 20):

That syntax works in my case:

```
<div class="col-md-3" *ng-for="#display of displays">
    <a [routerLink]="['/display-details', display.id]">
       <display-card ></display-card>
    </a>
</div>
```

with this router config:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', component: Home, as: 'home' },
  { path: '/display-details/:id', component: DisplayDetails }
])
```

Answer (score 8):

For the path: '/user/:id'

We can use in two way like /user;id:1234 or /user/123

```
// For /user;id:1234
[routerLink]="['/user', {id: display.id}]"
// For /user/1234
[routerLink]="['/user', display.id]"
```

I came here for my issue with path: '/customers/:id/detail' and finally finished with:

```
[routerLink]="['/customers', cust.id, 'detail']"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function in your component to get the dynamic URL and params by using routerLink and queryParams directive.

```
<div class="col-md-3" *ng-for="#display of displays">
    <a [routerLink]="getURL(display)" 
       [queryParams]="getParams(display)>
       <display-card ></display-card>
    </a>
</div>
```

in component:

```
getURL(display) { 
    return ['/displays', display.id];
}

getParams(display) { 
    return { param: display.somethingElse }; 
}
```